# Change colors of background-image gradient from code behind

Tags: css, asp.net, code-behind, linear-gradients

I am creating a login button like this:

```
<%-- login.aspx --%>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" OnClick="ButtonLoginClick" Text="Anmelden" CssClass="btn" />

/* CSS */
.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #003b67, #0067b4, #003b67);
    background-size: 200%;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
}


.btn:hover {
    background-position: right;
}
```

the result looks like this:
[image]

now, I am trying to change the colors of the gradient from code behind.
for example changing the text color just works fine

```
btnLogin.Style.Add("color", "#000");
```

changing the complete style also works like this:

```
btnLogin.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #ff0000, #ff0000)");
```

but then, only the background-image is set and all other style attributes are gone, for example the textcolor I set before.

So how can I only change background-image but keep all other attributes?

**EDIT:**

```
btnLogin.Style["color"] = "#000";               // works
btnLogin.Style["background-image"] = "linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #ff0000, #ff0000)";    // doesn't work
```

**EDIT 2:**
[image]
Error says: invalid property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like asp.net escapes/embeds the `background-image`-style always in urls - that's why this is not working:

```
btnLogin.Style["background-image"] = "linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #ff0000, #ff0000)";
```

What you can do is use `background` instead. It's a workaround for your case - but keep in mind, that `background` sets all properties of background at once, so e.g. your `background-size: 200%` needs to be set, if you really need it:

```
btnLogin.Style["background"] = "linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #ff0000, #ff0000)";
```

Comment: this does not work, there are no changes using this code

Comment: did you inspect the element on the client - is there any inline css rendered?

Comment: changed my answer again.